# How to automatically adjust whitespace after yanks?

Tags: whitespace, yank

When editing human language text and moving text fragments around, I frequently run into the problem that whitespace moved at the beginning or end of a fragment doesn't fit into the new position.  For example, consider this paragraph:

```
This is the first sentence.  This is the second sentence.  These
three sentences are the whole paragraph.
```

If I move the last sentence before the first one by kill+yank, I have either leading or trailing whitespace.  A similar problem occurs in enumerations.

Another use case is if I want to insert a single word or expression which is in the kill ring without any trailing or leading whitespace.  For example, consider the word "very" in the kill ring, and the following sentence:

```
Such a minor mode would be useful.
```

After yanking, this may erroneously become:

```
Such a minor mode would bevery useful.
```

Is there a way to have white space in human texts adjusted automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you have asked. By contrast if there is already extra white spaces, it keeps them as before.

```el
  (defun yank-and-adjust-whitespace ()
  (interactive)
  (if (equal (char-after) ?\s)
      (progn
        (insert " ")
        (yank))
    (if (eolp) (if (bolp) (yank)
        (if (equal (char-before) ?\s)
            (yank)
          (insert " ")
          (yank)))
      (yank)
      (insert " "))))
```

Like the answer of Eric Bailey you can associate the below shortcut.

```el
(global-set-key "\C-y" 'yank-and-adjust-whitespace)
```

Using `eolp/bolp` was borrowed from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13741/.

Comment: @wasamasa thanks for editing, I saw that you have changed `? ` to`?\s`. It seems that both work. I am interested to know about their differences.

Comment: Correct, both are equivalent.  The manual recommends `?\s` though because it looks a lot less confusing than `? ` and ensures that you meant to match a space instead of mistyping.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function, `delete-leading-whitespace-on-line` to do as the name suggests:

```lisp
(defun delete-leading-whitespace-on-line ()
  "Delete whitespace at the beginning of the current line."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (line-beginning-position))
        (end (line-end-position)))
    (save-excursion
      (delete-whitespace-rectangle start end nil))))
```

For *trailing* whitespace, I use `M-x delete-trailing-whitespace`.

To trigger these after yanks, you could do something like:

```lisp
(defun yank-and-trim-whitespace ()
  "Yank and then trim whitespace on the line."
  (interactive)
  (yank)
  (delete-leading-whitespace-on-line)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace))
```

and bind it like:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-y" 'yank-and-trim-whitespace)
```

---

You might also like to try Steve Purcell's [whitespace-cleanup-mode](https://github.com/purcell/whitespace-cleanup-mode), a minor mode that:

> will intelligently call whitespace-cleanup before buffers are saved.

PS His GitHub account is a treasure trove of Emacs goodies.

Comment: I don't have the reputation yet, but here's a link to the pertinent documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html

Comment: Are the `call-interactively`'s necessary here? Can you not just call the functions?

Comment: @erikstokes, good catch. The `call-interactively` are redundant.

Comment: I think using `call-interactively` here would make it work with `yank-pop`.