# Is there a variable which determines if the cursor is at the end or the beginning of the line

Tags: line-break

Is there a built-in boolean variable to determine if the cursor is at the end or the beginning of the line?

Comment: The functions `bolp` and `eolp` serve that purpose, but they are specifically concerned with `point` instead of `cursor`. In presence of invisible text, the cursor might look like it's at bol (beginning of line), but point might not be there. Do you care about such situations ?

Comment: @YoungFrog My question was concerned about `point`, and the answer of Dan is sufficient in my situation. If you know how to handle the `cursor` I would be happy to learn it.

Comment: My solution would involve skipping invisible text backwards and testing for `bolp`. I don't know if there's a better/shorter way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the functions `bolp` and `eolp` for beginning and end, respectively.

Comment: And the answer to the question is "no", there is no such variable. ;-)